# Sefardic Halacha online

Tags: product-recommendation

Is there any sefardic halachic book in english online that includes all the necessary topics(or at least most) for a jewish life?

(i checked peninei halacha but it doesnt have laws of haskamat haboker any many others)

Comment: Is there any work that contains all that?

Comment: There is the [Halacha Yomit](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx) website, which brings daily _Halakhot_, reponsa, or other _Divrei Torah_, based on the teachings of [R. Ovadia Yosef OBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovadia_Yosef), that are translated into English. I can't vouch for the extent of it's coverage of the necessary topics for a Jewish life, or it's accessibility by topic in English, though.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are looking for a compendium of Jewish Laws, a sort of "guidebook to living a Jewish life" from a Sephardic perspective. For centuries, the [Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Halakhah/Shulchan%20Arukh), written by Sephardic Rabbi [Joseph Karo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Karo) (born, Toledo, Spain 1488, died in 1575, Safed, Eretz Yisrael) has been treated as the definitive guide to halacha, living a Jewish life, and other matters by most Jews around the world. Some sections of the 4 volumes that make up the work have not been completely translated into English, but they are available online at absolutely no cost.

Answer (score 1):

The Institute of Sephardic Halacha (Halachot.com) sends out weekly pamphlets filled with halachot on different topics. You can sign up on their website to receive them. They do a very good job quoting the major Sephardic poskim in a very quick and concise way.